# Removing rows in csv using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a column called **key_resp_5_rt** and in it I would like to remove any rows that are under 300ms (it is a reaction time column)

```
for filename in files:
try:
    df=pd.read_csv(filename)

    df['key_resp_5.rt']
```

Can someone tell me if this code underneath can remove rows with rt's under 0.3 seconds?

```
    df[df['key_resp_5.rt'] > 0.3]
```

When I check afterwards the rows with values lower than 0.3 are still there and I can't figure out why

Comment: what's the datatype for `key_resp_5.rt` (`print(df.dtypes)`)? One guess is that it's a string, not a float. Also you have to assign the result back to the original dataframe: `df = df[[...]]`

Comment: Basically pandas dataframes are not mutable, you therefore need to assign the df again `df = df[df['key_resp_5.rt'] > 0.3] `

Comment: @nickthefreak Or alternatively assign to a new variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the return value to the same variable again in order to replace it. This does not happen in-place:

```py
df = df[df['key_resp_5.rt'] > 0.3]
```